# Is there a way I can pass value from my android app edittext to an aspx page textboxes?

Tags: android, asp.net

I am making an app in which the user enters username/password in my android app and the app transfers the value to My aspx page...(my own aspx website MySql Database) and then if the page proceeds after login...only den my app should proceed.
Or maybe someone can help me on how to connect to MySql Server to Android and do the proceedings.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel your question have been answered or your problem solved, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this sounds like you are building a login service? Normally you would not want to use an aspx page for this unless you have some very specific reasons for doing so, a much better and more common approach is to use a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) enabled webservice that you can communicate with.

Common practises for a login service written in C#.NET to be consumed by Android  includes https (more secure for password transfer) REST (easy to use with Android) and [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)

There are a lot of guides on how to write [restful webservices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201901/CREATE-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Using-POST-Step-By) online and I don't have a particular favourite but for a C# .NET developer WCF is always a good start before heading over to stuff like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) and similar.

Comment: No Actually my website is already up and running in aspx...so i just need some way to use the login service as u said...do u have any guide of using REST in android..?

Comment: I am not an Android dev but this one seems decent http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/